# Email Notification with Parse.com Cloud Code and SendGrid

Tags: javascript, email, parse-platform, sendgrid, parse-cloud-code

**CONTEXT:**

I am using Parse.com as the backend for my web application.  I want to send myself an email when a new user has signed up (i.e., a new record is saved to the 'User' table).  I am using the SendGrid Module for Parse.

**PROBLEM:**

The email does not send.  I neither receive a success nor error response.  Log files print "Step 2" but not "Step 3" (see below).

Also, I am not sure if "mySendGridFunction" refers to anything and needs to be changed.

**CODE:**

> Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
>       // Indicate Function Start
>       console.log("**********************************");
>       console.log("** New User Email Notification ***");
>       console.log("**********************************");
>
> ```
> // For New Users Only
> if(!(request.object.existed())){
>     // New User Identified
>     console.log("New user identified");
>
>     // Initialize SendGrid Module
>     var sendgrid = require("sendgrid");
>     sendgrid.initialize("myUsername", "myPassword");
>     console.log("Step 2");
>
>     // Send Email
>     Parse.Cloud.define("mySendGridFunction", function(request, response) {
>         console.log("Step 3");
>         sendgrid.sendEmail({
>             to: "me@mydomain.com",
>             from: "sendgrid@parse.com",
>             //from: "sendgrid@cloudcode.com",
>             subject: "Notification: New User",
>             text: "A new user has just signed up."
>         }, {
>             success: function(httpResponse) {
>                 console.log("User Notification email being sent");
>                 console.log("HTTP Response: " + httpResponse);
>                 response.success("User Notification email successfully sent");
>             },
>             error: function(httpResponse) {
>                 console.log("There was an error sending the User Notification email");
>                 console.error("HTTP Response: " + httpResponse);
>                 response.error("There was an error sending the User Notification email");
>             }
>         });
>     });
> }
> ```
>
> });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Alright, things are working!**  For those of you with a similar problem, I just removed the following line (and fixed closing brackets):

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("mySendGridFunction", function(request, response) {
```

I think this is only needed if you want to call a function that uses SendGrid.